# Python read .txt files and count matched with list from another document strings

Tags: python, text, counter, counting

I am trying to read .txt files and count how many matches are in each of them. I am using dictionary as a source of all specific words. I started writing the code, but I am not sure how to match all the words from dictionary to each .txt document.

Comment: what is the problem with this code and give sample input and output

Answer (score 1):

You're not too far off. You need to iterate the words in each line and check if they are in the dictionary. Also, you need to call `read_words`, otherwise `ret` doesn't exist in the `for` loop.

```
dictionary = read_words(dictionary)
for paper in library:
    file = os.path.join(path, paper)
    text = open(file, "r")
    hit_count = 0
    for line in text:
        for word in line:
            if word in dictionary:
                hit_count = hit_count + 1
                print >>  output, paper + "|" + line,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if any element in the list are in the line

**change  this from this :**

```
if re.match("(.*)(ret[])(.*)", line):
```

**To this :**

```
if any(word in line for word in ret)
```